# pip uninstall ipython failed

Tags: python, ipython

I want to uninstall `ipython`, but

```
user$ sudo pip uninstall ipython
Not uninstalling ipython at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

And

```
root# pip uninstall ipython
Not uninstalling ipython at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

Why I can not uinstall ipython?

My ipython is:

```
user$ ipython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

And after successfully upgraded ipython, the version of ipython is still 2.3.0. 
My OS is `Ubuntu 15.04`
What should I do to solve it.

Comment: The type of OS would help.

Comment: @Leb, OS is `ubuntu 15.04` 64bit

Comment: Have you ran it with `sudo` under root?

Answer (score 2):

Are you install ipython with `apt-get`? If so, please try:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ipython
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like IPython also was installed using `apt-get`. Uninstall it using

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ipython
```